# Image button on gridview not triggering asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

so i have a gridview with an imagebutton, thing is that it never triggers. I dont know why. here is the code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="233px" 
    OnCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
    DataKeyNames="Nombre">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="12%" ItemStyle-
            HorizontalAlign="Center" >
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkEditar" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" 
                  ImageUrl="Imagenes/edit.png" />
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and the code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        Label1.Text = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].ToString();
    }
}
```

I debugged it and it never triggers the RowCommand event. Any help is thanked!

Comment: are you using updatepanel?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change as follow `OnRowCommand`

```
OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
```

Comment: @nahuel and also try to change the command name to `Edit1` and check once